# It's possible to call goTo function after blockUI call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run code after blockUI, for instance, call goTo function.

```
if (respuesta.codigo != 0){
  if(respuesta.codigo==-34){
    $("#titulo_ventana_alerta").html('Datos recuperados correctamente');
    $("#texto_ventana_alerta").html(respuesta.mensaje+'<br>Presione <b>Aceptar</b> para continuar');
    $("#check_vet").attr("disabled",true);//bloqueamos la seleccion de veterinarios autorizados
    $.blockUI({message: $('#ventana_alerta'),css:{width:'303px'}});
    goTo(document,'<?php echo LOCAL_SERVER;?>','<?php echo CLIENT_PATH;?>','/plantillas/SolicitudGuiaMultiespeciePaso2').submit();
}else{         
     addWSError(respuesta.codigo,'solicitud_guiaMultiespecie',respuesta.mensaje);
     $("#texto_error").html(errors2HTML());
     $.blockUI({message:$('#ventana_error'),css:{width:'303px'}});
     }
}else {
   goTo(document,'<?php echo LOCAL_SERVER;?>','<?php echo CLIENT_PATH;?>','/plantillas/SolicitudGuiaMultiespeciePaso2').submit();
}
```

$.blockUI may be called in different cases, but in this case it shows a alert.
How Can I unblock the window

> I call unblockUI()

```
$('#yes2,#boton_aceptar_alerta').click(function() {
    $.unblockUI();
    return true;
});
```

Comment: PHP is executed before the page is even loaded.  Look at the source of your webpage.  You won't see any PHP at the top.  Additionally, you can't execute PHP in JavaScript.